# Not able to create a route in YII

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

I am really new to YII framework, its my first day using it so I am trying to understand how its route system work. I have set it up to use twig and I am able to render to landing page however i cant get to any other page other than the landing page as I get Object not found error.

This is what my `web.php` looks like

```
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'layout' => 'main.twig',
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
                    'globals' => ['html' => '\yii\helpers\Html'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'WgX2ZO_6a9zoA4XFJIuUGEUOB5x6WmJA',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            // Disable index.php
            'showScriptName' => false,
            // Disable r= routes
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Inside my `siteController` I have a `actionRegister`

```
public function actionRegister()
{
    return $this->render('register.twig');
}
```

I would like to access this `register` action with I access a URL `website/register`

Right now i get the error

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
```

I will really appreciate if someone can explain to me how the route works, I have gone through the documentation and I am lost...

Comment: The URL format should be module/controller/action. In your case it should be site/register. If you want to use website/register than you have to write a rule for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        'website/<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
    ]
]
```